# Find average per day, take latest if there is no record for the day

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure that the tile is correct nor specific..

I have a table that looks like this:

```
2013-01-01
a: 100

2013-01-02
b: 50

2013-01-03
c: 75
b: 200
```

Where "a, b, c" user ids.

I need a query that will return:

```
2013-01-01
100 / 1 = 100

2013-01-02
(100 + 50) / 2 = 75

2013-01-03
(100 + 200 + 75) / 3 = 125
```

[[2013-01-01, 100], [2013-01-02, 75], [2013-01-03, 125]]

It seems for a certein date I can do this with:

```
SELECT AVG(column1) FROM table a 
  JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(date) AS max_date, user_id FROM table 
     WHERE date < "2013-09-01" GROUP BY user_id) b 
   ON b.user_id = a.user_id AND a.date = b.max_date;
```

However, I have an interval which can be split by day, week, month or year: ['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02',... '2014-01-01'] (continuous)

Is there a faster way to do that instead of running 100 queries for a 100 day interval?

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d74fa/2

Desired result: 
single query that will return

```
2013-01-01, 100
2013-01-02, 75
2013-01-03, 125
```

Comment: Why does `c` not participate in 01-02, and `b` and `c` not in 01-01? Are they only valid for that average _after_ their first occurance? And are all dates guaranteed to be in there (no dates without _any_ record?)

Comment: @Wrikken, it is the most recent entry until the current interval day. There is no `c` until 01-03, so it does not participate in 01-02. There is no `a` in 01-02, so we take `a` from 01-01.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0):

If you need the daily average you have to use:

```
SELECT AVG(value)
FROM readings r
GROUP BY(date);
```

I am not sure why you are doing the average up to the day in the analytical description.